# Flutter RaisedButton not getting correctly rounded

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am learning to use Flutter, and now I just stumbled upon a problem when styling a button. Even following guides and questions here asked, my styled button appears "bugged", probably because of a problem in my code. Check how the button looks now:

[image]

This is my button's code (the problem is there, as it happens even only showing the button), and I think the problem is in the Container that I have inside, which is probably wrong, but I can't manage to find the problem:

```
 RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            textColor: Colors.white,
            shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
            ),
            child: Container(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  colors: <Color>[
                    Colors.purple,
                    Color.fromARGB(1, 247, 120, 150),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: const Text('Empezar partida',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            ),
          )
```

Comment: do you want that button to be fully filled?

Comment: @LonelyWolf my idea is that the inner button's gradient occupies the whole button shape, which is meant to be slightly round, with that border radius.

Answer (score 1):

check this code

```
RaisedButton(
 padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
   shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),),
  onPressed: () {},
  textColor: Colors.white,
  child: Container(
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)),
      gradient: LinearGradient(
        colors: <Color>[
          Colors.purple,
          Color.fromARGB(1, 247, 120, 150),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
    child: const Text('Empezar partida',
        style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20,
            color: Colors.white,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
  ),
),
```

Comment: Doesn't work either; I still see a padding between the internal Container (and its gradient), and the actual button: https://i.imgur.com/JY1Vp2j.png

Comment: add padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0) it will remove the padding also add shape for the raised button update my code check

Comment: I just fixed it adding specific paddings for every direction! I used your code and added to the Container() the following line:                   EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.0, top: 18, bottom: 18, right: 25)

now it works fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
Container(
             height: 50.0,
             margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
             child: RaisedButton(
               onPressed: () {},
               shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(80.0)),
               padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
               child: Ink(
                 decoration: BoxDecoration(
                     gradient: LinearGradient(
                       colors: [Color(0xff374ABE), Color(0xff64B6FF)],
                       begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                       end: Alignment.centerRight,
                     ),
                     borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                 child: Container(
                   constraints:
                       BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 250.0, minHeight: 50.0),
                   alignment: Alignment.center,
                   child: Text(
                     "Gradient Button",
                     textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                     style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15),
                   ),
                 ),
               ),
             ),
           ),
```

Use Ink widget to paint gradient in your button.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Ink-class.html

Comment: this one seems to work! It's not exactly how I wanted to display it, but it's something. Anyways, I'll put my answer since the specifics of my problem get solved with a different thing. I upvote your solution anyways!

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the solution of @AshwithSaldanha and @VarunKamani (there you have my upvote!), I managed to get into a different solution that fixes my problem well: I just used in my Container(), EdgeInsets.only() and provided the following parameters to fix it:

```
padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 27.0, top: 19, bottom: 19, right: 27)
```

This only works well if the RaisedButton() has a padding of 0:

```
padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0)
```

The final code looks like this:

```
      RaisedButton(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
        ),
        onPressed: () {},
        textColor: Colors.white,
        child: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)),
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: <Color>[
                Colors.purple,
                Color.fromARGB(1, 247, 120, 150),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          padding:
              EdgeInsets.only(left: 27.0, top: 19, bottom: 19, right: 27),
          child: const Text('Empezar partida',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 21,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        ),
      ),
```

And this is how it looks:

[image]

Comment: You still have the same problem. This solution will not work if your text is too short.https://codepen.io/varunkamani/pen/pogpbRp

Comment: That's true, but only for 1 letter text. 2 or 3 render nicely too, and it's fixable just changing the EdgeInsets.only() parameters. Which more general solution you would propose? If it does the same and work for all edge cases, I'll select it as the correct answer. Previous answers did not provide the expected result.